# How do I log request details for ActionController::RoutingErrors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, routes

I have a custom logger that extracts various headers (notably `REMOTE_ADDR` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`) from the `ActiveSupport::Notifications` event. This works fine for controller events, but when there's a `RoutingError`, we never hit the controller, and all the logger gets is the exception backtrace as a string. Is there another event I can subscribe to? How can I get access to the request object for requests fail before hitting a controller?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to implement some kind of middleware to catch errors that happen before reaching a controller action.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html

Maybe you can borrow some code from https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification or use it implementing a custom notifier https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#notifiers that uses your logger.